# Copying project files to server

Tags: windows, svn, netbeans, copy

I am using Netbeans to build my projects. I have used the option to automatically copy the source files to a different location that is located on a mapped network drive on my home server. This works for smaller projects but when I have a lot of data it is very slow for some reason.

I was wondering if I could use any other software that automatically copies changed files from location X on my local hard drive to a location Y on my network drive. I tried `mklink` but this doesn't work with network drives.

I already changed from SVN in Netbeans to TortoiseSVN. Committing happens in a few seconds with TortoiseSVN, Netbeans takes tens of minutes.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve for? Slow file transfers to a network share? It's not clear.

Comment: @alroc Netbeans takes forever to upload the files. If I manually copy files, it takes a minute maximum. Netbeans can take over half an hour.